# Rename the "Content Type" column in sharepoint online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I need to rename the default "Content Type" column in sharepoint online document library that has several content types. Is there a way to do it using CSOM or any other way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename default Content Type field name like this:

```
            List targetList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
            FieldCollection fields = targetList.Fields;
            ctx.Load(fields);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            Field ctfield = fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("ContentType");
            ctx.Load(ctfield);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            ctfield.Title = "CustomContentType";
            ctfield.Update();
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

[image]

[SharePoint Online: Rename a Column in List using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/08/sharepoint-online-rename-column-using-powershell.html)

Comment: Thanks, that indeed works. It didn't work for me before because of some localization issues. The name that I set was ignored until I switched the site to a correct language. Cannot explain this...